# Error: underlying connection was closed in sharepoint 2013 workflow in O365

Tags: workflow, office-365, designer-workflow

Getting intermittent error: underlying connection was closed in SharePoint 2013 workflow in O365 when activating a the feature for the workflow or trying to associate the workflow to a library.
It works fine most of the time. But sometimes gives the error message. 
Any suggestions?

Comment: Kindly check this...http://kb.odin.com/en/128657

Comment: Kindly check this as well....http://geekswithblogs.net/Denis/archive/2005/08/16/50365.aspx

Comment: Can you please share me (add in question) your findings for this issue? so I will try to help you better.